# Counter increment on image load on server

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want counter hit increment i.e. to be save in database, Whenever a perticular image will preview on site/server.

For Eg: http://test.com/1234(ad_no)/1.jpg whenever this url going to load on site 
hit counter code should increase.But not in brower, like following code in html view not html source.

```
<div align="center"><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="75%;"><tbody><tr><td width="100%;"><a href="http://www.test.com/27123"> <img border="1" src="http://www.test.com/27123/1.jpg" width="720" height="541" /></a></td></tr></tbody></table></center></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `<img src="image.png" alt="Image"/>` use this:

```
<img src="load_image.php" alt="Image"/>
```

Now at load_image.php use the following code:

```
<?php 
    //Connect mysql server
    ....

    //Update your count
    ....

    //Return the image
    $image = file_get_contents('location/myimage.png'); 
    header('content-type: image/png'); 
    echo $image;
?>
```

It will first execute the php and then simply return the image file required. So this way you can keep a track of how many times that image was requested. This is the way most tracking pixels work.

Answer (score 0):

you want to log showing of your image from another server?

You could do it with

- Access log proccessing
- Disallow direct access to jpg file and allow it for example on ad.php?image=/yourimage/url.jpg and then save it directly

Comment: No image will be on same server, Just want when ever this image(1.jpg) load or preview anywhere on the site request should send to server and update query should fire.